# Proximity map does not match up with original data

Tags: qgis, proximity, gdal-proximity

I have a vector layer of paths that I want to create a distance map from. so I converted the layer to a raster layer and ran `raster > analysis > promixity` on it. the problem is that the result does not align with the input layer anymore. now I am trying to figure out why / how to fix this.

[image: screenshot]

as you can see the proximity map should align with the orange areas.

I'm a (q)gis noob; my assumption is that I need to use a different projection, but I wouldn't know which one. the qgis project uses `epsg:3857` and the original vector layer is `epsg:4326`.

Comment: @user2856 that did it — thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reproject](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisreprojectlayer) your vector to [EPSG:25833](https://epsg.io/25833) before rasterizing, then run the proximity. EPSG:3857 and EPSG:4326 are not useful for distance based analyses.

Technically UTM is a [conformal projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map_projection) (preserves angles, distorts distances) but this distortion is negligible for your small area within a [UTM zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#UTM_zone).